# How to delay animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery animation which renders curtains opening and closing on the click function of `.rope`

When the page loads the curtains automatically open after adding

```
$(".rope").trigger('click');
```

to the end of the string.

The full code works great but when the page loads, I want it to delay for a few seconds before the curtains open, but not on the click. I've tried adding .delay(2000) before .animate and before .ready, I'm toying around with a setTimeout but I',m not sure where to put it or if it's even what I need. My javascript skills is pretty basic. Here is what I'm using. I just want to add the delay

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $curtainopen = false;

            $(".rope").click(function(){
                $(this).blur();
                if ($curtainopen == false){ 
                    $(this).stop().animate({top: '0px' }, {queue:false, duration:500, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
                    $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'60px'}, 2000 );
                    $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'60px'},2000 );
                    $curtainopen = true;
                }else{
                    $(this).stop().animate({top: '-40px' }, {queue:false, duration:500, easing:'easeOutBounce'}); 
                    $(".leftcurtain").stop().animate({width:'50%'}, 2000 );
                    $(".rightcurtain").stop().animate({width:'51%'}, 2000 );
                    $curtainopen = false;
                }
                return false;
            });
            $(".rope").trigger('click');
        });
```

Comment: just move the contents of the click function to an outer function and call that in the click listener, and also on page load. Or you could do `$('.rope').delay(2000).trigger('click');`

Comment: @KaiQing No, `.delay()` only works for animation queues, and `.trigger()` is not part of it.

Comment: fair enough. set timeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A timeout would be ideal for this, I think.

```
var autoOpen = setTimeout(function() {
    $(".rope").trigger("click");
},2000);
```

Be sure to add this just inside your `$(".rope").click(...)` function:

```
clearTimeout(autoOpen);
```

This will ensure that if the user clicks manually, then it cancels the "open automatically after two seconds" thing which might otherwise interfere ;)

Comment: Thanks . I'm going to give this a shot. Should the code for the clearTimeout look like this? $(".rope").click(clearTimeout(autoOpen);)(function(){......

Comment: I said *inside* the function.